# Docker compose ecs fails to deploy (fails when using docker compose up)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am trying to determine why the cloudformation building of application fails when trying to create resources for BackgroundjobsService (Create failed in cloudformation). The only main differences from other services I have built is that it has no exposed ports and I am using ubuntu instead of php-apache image.

Dockerfile (I made it super simply (basically do nothing)

```
# Pulling Ubuntu image
FROM ubuntu:20.04
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  background_jobs:
    image: 000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/company/job-scheduler
    restart: always
    env_file: ../.env.${ENV}
    build:
      context: "."
```

How I deploy (I verified the enf files exist in the parent directory of job-scheduler).

```
cd job-scheduler
ENV=dev docker --context default compose build
docker push 000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/company/job-scheduler:latest
ENV=dev docker --context tcetra-dev compose up
```

I don't know how to find any sort of error logs but the task defination gets created and all my env vars are in there.

Comment: Try to add 'CMD' instruction to your Dockerfile

Comment: Did you check the cloudformation events? Did you tried locally? Is you first deploy on cloudformation?